# how to show interstitial ad in swift 5 with navigation button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob, viewcontroller

I'm creating Ann app with a ViewController that has three buttons that lead to other three ViewControllers ...

I want my interstitial ad to be shown when user click the button. When the ad finish, view controller appears and when user closes view controller and go to the root view controller and try to open another view controller the ad appear and then view controller.

My code below make ad appear but after finish don't open target view controller.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import GoogleMobileAds



class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var interstitialad : GADInterstitial!
    
      
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.interstitialad = createAd()
            
    }
    @IBAction func news(_ sender: Any) {
        
        if interstitialad?.isReady == true {
            interstitialad?.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        }
      
    }
    
    @IBAction func table(_ sender: Any) {
                
                
                
                
                
        if interstitialad?.isReady == true {
            interstitialad?.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        }

    }
    @IBAction func channels(_ sender: Any) {
            
            
            
        if interstitialad?.isReady == true {
            interstitialad?.present(fromRootViewController: self)


        }
                  
    }
    private func createAd() ->GADInterstitial {
        
        let ad = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
        ad.delegate = self
        ad.load(GADRequest())
        return ad
    }
    
    
    
    
   

}

extension ViewController: GADInterstitialDelegate{
   
    func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {

        interstitialad = createAd()
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Is your `interstitialDidDismissScreen` function getting called?

Comment: no it is not called